# Android EditText not increasing but reducing instead

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext

I have an issue with my EditText in android
I want the control's height to fit it's content but it's not working.

This is the configuration of the EditText :

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtPublicComment"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:maxLength="2000"
                android:minLines="8"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left|top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                style="@style/EditTextDarkGreyLightBorder"
                />
```

Instead of growing, the control is reducing his height when I press ENTER. I don't really know why.

And this is the whole fragment :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/activity_background"
tools:context="computerland.com.mobilenew.TimeSheetEditFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/BoxWhite">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_comment"
                style="@style/TextViewGreyMediumItalicCaps"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtPublicComment"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:maxLength="2000"
                android:minLines="8"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left|top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                style="@style/EditTextDarkGreyLightBorder"
                />

        </LinearLayout>





    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The following line

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

is modifying the height and preventing it from just wrapping the content

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Same result with  or without the layout_weight 1

Answer (score 0):

Try and hard code your width.

```
  <EditText
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtPublicComment"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:maxLength="2000"
            android:minLines="8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            style="@style/EditTextDarkGreyLightBorder"
            />
```

Comment: Didn't change anything, same result (with now the bad width)